# Glassfish doesn't process SPI jars

Tags: java, glassfish, spi

I use an external jar file that is supposed to be used as a service provider (SPI) - it contains directory META-INF/services with information about services it provides.
Then I build an EAR and add this jar into it as a library. Deploy this EAR on Glassfish.
Glassfish loads this jar, although as a ordinary jar - not as a Service Provider. Looks like its dorectory META-INF/services is just ignored.
Then, if I put this jar into domain/lib/ext directory of the Glassfish, as an external dependency, it starts working. What might be a reason of it?